# Unique browser session with webdriver

Tags: webdriver

Does webdriver maintain unique browser sessions by default when used with multiple threads i.e multiple tests in parallel? If not then how do I make it maintain unique sessions?

Answer (score 0):

By 
Using TestNG , we can open multiple browser session (firefox) and run tests.

Answer (score 0):

I am closer to "no" - If I run my tests in Selenium Grid and some browser window "dies" (hangs up unexpectedly, because I am bad programmer), restarting the tests cause my webapp to tell me "another user with same user name is already logged in"

But in normal Selenium Webdriver, calling `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` caused new session. Always.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Grid configuration; It is exactly what you need.See here an [example of parallel test run](http://qtp-help.blogspot.co.at/2011/09/selenium-grid-with-webdriver.html).
Grid can support multiple sessions. You can configure this when you register your node to the hub, using parameters : `-maxSession x -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=x`, where x represents desired number of sessions.